# Render rails partial on select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a nested_form that looks like:

```
<% form_for @store, do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :products do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.select :typeis, %w[test test1 test2], {}, class: "select_product" %>
      <div class='productHere'></div>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Basically, what I want to do is onChange of the select, take the value of the select and render a partial like:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :name, value: "blah" %>
```

using the value. So if the value of the select is **test1**, I want to render _test1.html.erb.

I've tried doing:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function (){
     $(".select_product").on("change", function (){
        alert(<%= render 'product_form/test', f:builder %>);
     });
  });
</script>
```

But this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: your jQuery selector is using 'select_product' class instead of 'selectProduct'. so change '$(".select_product")' to '$(".selectProduct")'

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar, Thanks, but still didn't fix the issue.

Comment: do you see any errors on cosole?

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar, No, no errors.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127934/rendering-partial-in-js-erb-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are creating select dropdown dynamically, then you need to bind change event using below code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function (){
     $(document).on("change",".selectProduct", function (){
        var selectValue = $(this).val();
        alert(<%= render 'product_form/test', f:builder %>);
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @Bshushan Kawadkar, thanks this fixed my problem! Do you know how could I use the value of the select in the render call? So if the user selects "test1", I render `product_form/test1`?

Comment: you can get select value using '$(this).val();'. use this in the render call. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! But is there any way to interpolate between ruby and javascript so I could do something like: `alert(<%= render 'product_form/#{selectValue}', f:builder %>);`?

Comment: Sorry but I am not aware of ruby much :(