# Render a form after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, css

I am trying to render a form after a previous form is submitted. For instance, let's say I have a form that only has a select dropdown menu. You choose one of the options, click 'continue' (the submit button) and after the page reloads, it renders a new form depending on the chosen category.

FYI, I am trying to do this in a Rails App.

Here is an example: http://popcornindiana.com/contact-us

Comment: What code have you written so far? And what is your question?

Comment: If you consider loading form upon changing the selected option, then this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277233/render-rails-partial-on-select-change

Answer (score 2):

The example you provided is a page-by-page example. If you're looking to do that, then your form should submit to another page, which then has the next form on it as a seperate document altogether. Note how when you submit one form, the URL changes. Its a different page entirely.

Now, if you're looking to do single-page forms (where you hit submit and the page doesn't refresh, but rather the form refreshes), you're looking to use *asynchronous form submission*. There are many approaches to doing this, including rolling your own, using jQuery, or a large framework like AngularJS.

Those are the two possible approaches, which you choose based off your requirements is up to you.

I would look up tutorials on either method; the nature of the question indicates that you may be fairly inexperienced in this so I'd say look up tutorials on how to submit forms, and then decide which way to go after that.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses. I know i could just have the form and display them or hide them depending on the element clicked, but i am trying to accomplish that exact behavior (the example in popcornindiana.com). I want to select an option, click continue, go to another page and get a form based on the option previously selected. I know i will have to create a page and a route for each form, but dont know how to go to those specific urls in relation to the option selected.

Comment: I didn't play with it enough to realize that you selection dictated which page you were sent to. You can also look at the source: they have javascript submitting the form to the page that is equal to the value of the select option that was selected. Straightforward enough, but probably not the safest way to do it since if javascript breaks in some way or a browser has JS disabled, that form will be dead entirely. That hurts your bottom line from a business perspective.

Comment: Thanks #dodewad! Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Well the problem is you can go in about a million different ways with it. My question is, why would you want a different URL for each form selection? Unless you're looking to "deep link" to those pages, but from my perspective it might be better to force the entire user flow and just have a "submission" page.

That said, you answered your own question - route it from the app server. That seems acceptable to me!

Answer (score 0):

Write specific URL for each select item in their params. And use redirect_to params[:url] in controller.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually way easier that I would have ever imagined. I guess I got more confused because I was thinking in Rails terms instead of goo'old HTML. Anyways, I will share the complete solution:

1. Create a route for the view, one example is:

   ```
   config/routes.rb

   # this one is the hub, where you choose the contact form you need
   get 'contact' => 'contacts#contact_page'

   # this is the 'new' action, where the contact will be created
   get '/contacts/love-us' => 'contacts#love_us'
   ```
2. Create controller actions:

   ```
   app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb

   class ContactsController < ApplicationController
       before_action :send_email, except: [:create]

       def create
           @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
           @contact.request = request
           if @contact.deliver
               @thank   = "Thank you!"
               @message = "We received your inquiry."
           else
               @error   = "Cannot send message"
           end
       end

       # to the select where you choose the contact form
       def contact_page
       end

       # to the actual contact form
       def love_us
           @the_subject = "Tell us you love us"
       end

       # def ... other actions to other contact forms

       private
           def send_email
               @contact = Contact.new
           end
   end
   ```
3. Create one view for each form, in this example:

   ```
   app/views/contacts/love-us.html.haml

   .contact-page
       %h3 Tell Us You Love Us
       = form_for @contact do |f|
           .hide
               = f.text_field   :nickname,     hint: 'Leave this empty!'
               = f.hidden_field :mail_subject, value: @the_subject
           = f.label            :name
           = f.text_field       :name
           = f.label            :message      
           = f.text_area        :message       
           = f.submit "Send Message"
   ```
4. Create 'contact_page' the view to select the desired contact form

   ```
   app/views/contact/contact_page.html.haml

   .contact-form
       %h5 Select a Subject:
       %form{class: "emailform", name: "emailform"}
           %select{name: "location", class: "store-select"}
               %option{selected: "selected", :value => "/contact"}
                   = "---"
               %option{value: "/contacts/where-to-buy"}
                   WHERE TO BUY
               %option{value: "/contacts/nutritional-ingredients"}
                   NUTRITIONAL AND / OR INGREDIENTS
               %option{value: "/contacts/order-status"}
                   ORDER STATUS AND TRACKING
               %option{value: "/contacts/product-complaint"}
                   SPECIFIC PRODUCT COMPLAINT
               %option{value: "/contacts/company-related"}
                   COMPANY RELATED OR OTHER
               %option{value: "/contacts/love-us"}
                   TELL US YOU LOVE US
           %input{name: "submit", type: "button", value: "Continue", onclick: "self.location=document.emailform.location.value"}/
   ```