# Passing dynamic subject to Rails mail_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mail-form

I am using gem mail_form to handle contact in a Rails app, and I have 6 different contact forms.

I put a hidden_field_tag in the form and pass the desired subject as a variable. In the html, the value is there but **the email arrives with (no subject)**. What can I be doing wrong?

In controllers

```
def where_to_buy
   @contact = Contact.new
   @the_subject = "Where to buy"
end
```

In contact form

```
= form_for @contact do |f|
  = render "form", f: f
  = f.text_area :message
  .hide
    = f.text_field :nickname, hint: 'Leave this field empty!'
    = hidden_field_tag    :mail_subject, @the_subject
  = f.submit "Send Message"
```

In model

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :mail_subject
  attribute :first_name, validate: true
  attribute :last_name,  validate: true
  attribute :message,    validate: true
  attribute :nickname,   captcha:  true

  def headers
    {
      subject: %(#{mail_subject}),
      to:      "jorge@email123.com",
      from:    %("#{first_name} #{last_name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

Output html in chrome:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mail_subject" id="mail_subject" value="Where to buy">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
= hidden_field_tag :mail_subject, @the_subject
```

You will want to use:

```
= f.hidden_field :mail_subject, value: @the_subject
```

If you inspect the parameters that are logged into your `development.log` you will see why.

When you use `hidden_field_tag` the `mail_subject` is defined as its own independent parameter and will not be included in the `contact` hash.  You'll have something like:

```
params = { "contact" => { "message" => "text here", ... }, "mail_subject => "Where to buy" }
```

But when you use `f.hidden_field` the `mail_subject` will be included in the `contact` hash.  You'll have something like:

```
params = { "contact" => { "message" => "text here", "mail_subject => "Where to buy", ... } }
```

And then when you call `Contact.new(params[:contact])` the new contact object will get the `mail_subject` value.

Comment: Doode! Knowledge is priceless! I have tried so many things, including using value: @the_subject, and using f.hidden_field, but for some reason I never tried them both together. It now works perfect. I should have asked before spending 2 hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Cool.  Then if you wanted to remove the use of the `@the_subject` variable you should be able to have your `where_to_buy` action do `@contact = Contact.new(mail_subject: "Where to buy")` and the view could just use `= f.hidden_field :mail_subject`.

Comment: That is amazing. And now that I think about it, it makes a lot of sense. Thanks again!

Comment: By the way, do you have any opinion on this one?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618138/render-a-form-after-form-submission