# Rendering erb partial within JS file renders a string

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, partial

I am trying to render a partial inside my js file and append it to my html on a javascript event (click). I tried to follow this and use the escape_javascript method : [Rendering partial in js.erb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127934/rendering-partial-in-js-erb-file)
but unfortunately it doesnt work.
This is my js file :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#add_resident").click(function(){
          $(".resident").append('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "resident_form") %>');

        })

})
```

this is my partial :

```
<%= label_tag "first name" %>
<%= text_field_tag "resident[:first_name]" %>
<%= label_tag "last name"%>
<%= text_field_tag "resident[last_name]" %>
<%= label_tag "birthdate"%>
<%= text_field_tag "resident[birthdate]" %>
```

the javascript is indeed triggered on the .click event but it is rendering <%= escape_javascript(render partial: "resident_form") %> as a string. What is the correct way to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Hey your code should be:

```
$("#add_resident").click();
$(".resident").append('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "resident_form") %>');
```

That's all, don't need this code `$(document).ready(function(){})`, because when server returns this javascript, your view was ready already!

Comment: Ok but even with the document ready my partial is still not rendering on the string <%= escape_javascript(render partial: "resident_form") %> is rendered

Comment: Is `$(".resident")` existing?

Comment: yes $(".resident") is existing, the JS is actually triggered on the click event. The problem is that instead of rendering my partial it is rendering <%= escape_javascript(render partial: "resident_form") %> as a string

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the JS rendered.

```
$(".resident").append('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "resident_form").html_safe %>');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get <%= escape_javascript(render partial: "resident_form").html_safe %> appended to my html...